# How can I check whether the input buffer is empty?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port

I'm trying to write a simple class for operating a Serial Port on Windows, using standart windows library  .

I need to check whether the input buffer is empty.

So far I've tried to use SetCommEvent, using EV_RXCHAR option, however this method doesn't work. The function seems to wait for arrival of new char. If I tried to send char, sleep for a second and the apply this, the function would not return - it keeps waiting.

```
bool isEmpty()
{
    DWORD dwEventMask = 0;
    DWORD Status = 0;

    if (CheckAsyncRead())
        return false;

    if (!SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR)) //wait for char receival
        std::cout << "Error in creating Overlapped event" << std::endl;

    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwEventMask, &osReader))
    {
                //close event handle
        return false;
    }

    Status = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent, 10);

        //I wait for 10 ms in case the function doesn't return immediately
    //Close event handle

    if (Status == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;

}
```

I hoped the WaitCommEvent or WaitForSingleObject would return in case any chars were present in buffer but the does not happen if there is a longer pause between receival of a character and calling of Wait function.

Comment: Are you calling `SetCommTimeouts`?  With what values?

Comment: Yes. Right now I my settings are: 
ReadIntervalTimeout = 2;
ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
tReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ClearCommError function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror) to find out the size of the data stored in the buffer.

As a result of calling, cbInQue of the [COMSTAT structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror) to be notified has the size of the data stored in the input buffer.

Comment: Thank you. Precisely what I needed.

Comment: Be careful because `ClearCommError()` has side effects.  Do not treat it as a passive getter!  (These side effects are the source of a major bug in the .NET SerialPort class)

Comment: @Ben Voigt, If there are detailed information or link about the cause and measures, please introduce.

Comment: The side effects are described on the MSDN page you linked to.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Is premature return of WaitCommEvent one of these side effects? Because I currently face such a problem.

Comment: @RadekHlavinka: Are you sure you aren't seeing a side effect of `SetCommMask`?  That's documented to cause `WaitCommEvent` to return immediately.  It's possible that `ClearCommError` is implicated but the documented interaction seems more likely to be the culprit.  I was referring to the fact that all the error information gets cleared by the call.  The bug in .NET is two threads calling `ClearCommError`, one using the error information, one using the input buffer length and discarding errors.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I am positive. I tried going through the code step by step and added simple markers to any use of `SetCommEvent` (simple write to `std::cout`). The thread enters the waiting state and exits a while later proceeding to `ReadFile`, where it waits indefinitely, because the buffer is empty, no data is to be sent and I don't use `Total timeout`. What really riddles me is the fact, that this appears only in the second pass of the thread - in 1st pass the thread waits for char receival as it is supposed to.

Comment: @Radek Hlavinka, It would be better to ask new question along with detailed information.

Comment: @RadekHlavinka: It's `SetCommMask`, not `SetCommState` (and I don't even see a function named `SetCommEvent`), that interrupts `WaitCommEvent`.

Comment: @RadekHlavinka: I would still challenge you to design your class so you do not need to ask how much data is in the buffer.  Instead, just get whatever data is there (set the read total timeout to zero as described in `COMMTIMEOUTS`) and then check the length of the data you got.  Even apart from the `ClearCommError` side effects, the buffer length you got is out of date before the function even returns to you, so you are forced into a TOCTOU logic error.

Comment: I created new question where I tried to better explain the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697983/waitforsingleobject-gets-signalled-without-occurence-of-awated-event). Also I don't use `ClearCommError` to get amount of data in input buffer, just to see whether there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReadFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) with a handle opened with [CreateFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) with the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag. If the ReadFile() function has nothing to return, it will return a last error ERROR_IO_PENDING  which means that your buffer is currently empty.

Comment: The timeout settings also matter.  In fact, only the timeout settings matter.