# WaitForSingleObject() gets signalled without occurrence of awaited event

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm writing a Class for COM ports in C++ using win-api. Righ now I test the functionality on RS232 with connected Rx and Tx pins.

I've encountered somewhat weird problem. I use separate thread for reading from the COM port. Within the thread I use `SetCommMask`, `WaitCommEvent` and `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for char arrival into buffer. However the `WaitForSingleObject` tends to exit without actually receiving any chars.

I assumed this was caused by wrong use of mentioned functions, but then I discovered, that premature exit does not occur every time (first time always works as intended).

In second go the thread enters the waiting state and exits a while later proceeding to `ReadFile`, where it waits indefinitely, because the buffer is empty, no data is to be sent and Total timeout is not used.

I've already been advised to simply use `ReadFile` and process only the data I acquire, however I use another thread to check if the communication channel has been disconnected and right now I need to distinguish between waiting for data and reading data.

Calling `ClearCommError` to check input buffer with `ReadFile` is not an option, because in such a case `InQue` is always 0. Therefore I cannot tell whether `ReadFile` is actually reading or waiting.

```
    //following code runs in separate thread
    DWORD dwEventMask1, dwEventMask2, LastError, Status;
    OVERLAPPED Overlapped; HANDLE Serial_Port_Handle;
    std::string stringBuffer("");
    const size_t ReadBufferLength = 256;
    char tempBuffer[ReadBufferLength];

    GetCommMask(Serial_Port_Handle, &dwEventMask1);



    if (dwEventMask1)   // Before starting the thread I check the state of Input Buffer with GetCommError().
    {                   // If Buffer is not empty, CommMask is set to 0 signaling there is no need for waiting.
        Overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

        //wait for comm event
        if (!WaitCommEvent(Serial_Port_Handle, &dwEventMask1, &Overlapped))
        {
            if ((LastError = GetLastError()) == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                Waiting = true; //signal bool for synchronization purposes
                if ((Status = WaitForSingleObject(Overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE)) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    GetCommMask(Serial_Port_Handle, &dwEventMask2);
                    Waiting = false;
                    CloseHandle(Overlapped.hEvent); 
                    // I close handle and set all members of Overlapped struct to 0
                } 

                if (dwEventMask2 !== dwEventMask1) // check if wait have not exited because of SetCommMast()
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
    do  // this loop reads from input buffer until empty
    {
        Overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);//set up read overlapped operation

        if (ReadFile(Serial_Port_Handle, tempBuffer, ReadBufferLength - 1, &NoBytesRead, &Overlapped)) //start read opperation
        { //Read operation done on 1 go
            GetOverlappedResult(Serial_Port_Handle, &Overlapped, &NoBytesRead, FALSE); //get NoBytesRead

            CloseHandle(Overlapped.hEvent)
            stringBuffer.append(tempBuffer, (size_t) NoBytesRead); // save read data
        }
        else if ((LastError = GetLastError()) == ERROR_IO_PENDING) //operation not yet complete
        {
            GetOverlappedResult(Serial_Port_Handle, &Overlapped, &NoBytesRead, TRUE); // wait for completion
            stringBuffer.append(tempBuffer, (size_t)NoBytesRead);
        }
        else
        {
            CloseHandle(Overlapped.hEvent)
            return;
        }
    } while ((NoBytesRead == (ReadBufferLength - 1)) && NoBytesRead);
    // Loop runs while tempBuffer's full capacity is used.
    // I realize that since I don't use Total Timeout there is a possibility
    // of the loop getting stuck. If you can suggest other solution than using
    // Total Timeout or use GetCommError() to get input buffer state, please do so.
    return;
```

This code is somewhat simplified (checking for return values, ets.).

1) Have any of you experienced such a behaviour?

2) I use OVERLAPPED operations in the code. After the operation exits I always use `CloseHandle` and reinitialize the OVERLAPPED structure before using it for another operation. Is this correct or is resetting the structure sufficient?

Comment: too complex and not efficient logic, resource leaks, etc. if you use event completion (the worst way, and not clear for what you use here at all instead synchronous io, if you do loop in separate thread) - use `GetOverlappedResult` instead `WaitForSingleObject` on event. however if event set in signal state this mean that io operation is complete. possible with `STATUS_TIMEOUT` error, but win32 level simply lost this error status and wrong say that all ok.

Comment: I don't see any mention of serial ports among the [things that WaitForSingleObject can wait for] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject).

Comment: There is just no point in using overlapped I/O when you don't do anything else but wait for the I/O to complete.  You then need a thread, but you already got that.  So keep it short and simple, pass NULL instead and don't use WFSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad logic as a whole. For example, there are the following issues.

- CreateEvent/CloseHandle should not executed at every ReadFile/WaitCommEvent.
- The usage of GetCommMask/WaitCommEvent is also wrong.
- The read data size specified in ReadFile is fixed regardless of the situation.
- It also includes the comment on @RbMm.

You may want to redesign your program with reference to the following articles and source code:

[Synchronization and Overlapped Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output)

[Serial Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff802693(v=msdn.10))

[bmo/mttty](https://github.com/bmo/mttty)

---

**In Addition:**
I did not notice that a file handle (not an event handle) was specified for WaitForSingleObject, as pointed out by @Rita Han.
The biggest problem is that.

However, the situation that it is better to redesign has not changed.
There is no description of WaitCommEvent and Overlapped for it in the source of @Rita Han's answer. Also, the read data size is fixed in ReadFile.

---

**On the other hand:**
Although it does not occur in the source code of the question, it is possible for WaitCommEvent/WaitForSingleObject to generate an event that is not specified in SetCommMask.

- While the WaitCommEvent is waiting for completion, change the event mask with SetCommMask.
  [Remarks - WaitCommEvent function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-waitcommevent#remarks)

  > If a process attempts to change the device handle's event mask by using the SetCommMask function while an overlapped WaitCommEvent operation is in progress, WaitCommEvent returns immediately. The variable pointed to by the lpEvtMask parameter is set to zero.
- While WaitCommEvent is waiting for completion, call WaitCommEvent multiple times using the same Overlapped structure.
  [Synchronization and Overlapped Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output)

  > When performing multiple simultaneous overlapped operations on a single thread, the calling thread must specify an OVERLAPPED structure for each operation. Each OVERLAPPED structure must specify a handle to a different manual-reset event object.
  >
  > A thread should not reuse an event with the assumption that the event will be signaled only by that thread's overlapped operation. An event is signaled on the same thread as the overlapped operation that is completing. Using the same event on multiple threads can lead to a race condition in which the event is signaled correctly for the thread whose operation completes first and prematurely for other threads using that event.

The document is described as above, but depending on the device driver/vendor, the WaitCommEvent that is called later ends with an error, and the WaitCommEvent waiting for completion is lpEvtMask return with zero (as in SetCommMask).

---

**For multiple Overlapped structure variables:**
A common programming know-how is that using a single variable for multiple purposes is prone to bugs.
If you are designing in asynchronous and/or multi-threading, it is better to prepare at least three Overlapped structure variables for ReadFile, WriteFile, WaitCommEvent.

**About starting ReadFile regardless of the state of the input buffer:**
This is about calling ReadFile with a fixed length of 256 bytes without acquiring the size of the received data in the input buffer of the device driver.

In fact, even if all the data arrives, if it is less than 256 bytes, it will always be delayed until a 256 byte receive timeout occurs.

For example, the loop reads one byte at a time until a timeout error occurs, which means the end of the received data (1-byte read timeout would have no impact).
Or, as answered in the previous article, use ClearCommError to obtain the size of the data stored in the device driver's input buffer, and call ReadFile specifying that size.

There will be no problem with the application-side buffer handling you are explaining.

**About the behavior of WaiCommEvent when calling SetCommMask:**
It may depend on the device driver you are using.

Comment: I do not use serial port handle as an argument for WaitForSingleObject() in my original code. I made this mistake while rewriting code for this question. I apologise for that.

When it comes to CrateEvent and CloseHandle, I understand from comments bellow that each function restarts events on it's own. However do I really need 2 OVERLAPPED structures, if I know that only one overlapped operation will be executed?

Comment: When you write of bad logic, do you refer to the fact, that since the code runs in a separate thread, all functions could be performed synchronously? I realized this while back, but I did not have time to change this. Or do you mean that I should start `ReadFile` regardless of the state of input buffer and use `WaitCommEvent` only for information purposes?

Comment: I know of the constant buffer length, however I tried to design the code in such a way for it not to be a factor. It serves only as a temporary buffer before saving data into `std::string`. I hoped to use this method and save myself some work having to reallocate additional space in `char` array. Do you consider this a bad practise? Could you specify why?

Comment: When it comes to the behaviour of `WaitCommEvent` when `SetCommMask` is called, I am aware of it and checked for it - it does not occur.

Comment: @RadekHlavinka For individual OVERLAPPED structure, it is suggested. [A common mistake is to reuse an OVERLAPPED structure before the previous asynchronous operation has been completed. You should use a separate structure for each request.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped#remarks)

Comment: Hi kunif, I focused on the usage of winapi instead of C++ programming logic. And also for fixed size of buffer, it is just en example for testing purpose. However it is good for you to point out the best practice for programming. I believe it will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have altered the code to use 2 OVERLAPPED structures, however I still think it not nescessary, since I do not reuse the structure before the previous operation completed. The text you refer to specifies that. I was using 2 OVERLAPPED strustures in earlier version of the code, it however seemed unnecessary to use 2 OVERLAPPED structures for 2 events that do not take place simultaneously

Comment: @RadekHlavinka It is ok for you if you make sure the previous operation completed. So the issue in your question solved?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: Yes. I've managed to resolve the premature exit of `WaitForSingleObject` by setting comm mask to 0 after event occured. I did not realize, that the system monitors communication events regardless of  me calling `WaitCommEvent` or not.

Answer (score 0):

> However the WaitForSingleObject tends to exit without actually
>   receiving any chars.

Wait for the event handle instead of serial device handle.

I got it working. The following is my code example you can have a try:

```
DWORD errCode = 0;
BOOL result = false;

HANDLE serialDeviceHdl = CreateFile(L"COM8", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
if (!serialDeviceHdl)
{
    errCode = GetLastError();
    cout << "Open device failed. Error code: " << errCode << endl;
    return 0;
}

OVERLAPPED overlappedForWrite = {};
overlappedForWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

DWORD writenSize = 0;
result = WriteFile(serialDeviceHdl, "hello", 5, &writenSize, &overlappedForWrite);
if (FALSE == result)
{
    errCode = GetLastError();
    if (ERROR_IO_PENDING == errCode)
    {
        cout << "Overlapped I/O operation is in progress." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Write to device failed. Error code: " << errCode << endl;
    }
}

DWORD returnValue = WaitForSingleObject(overlappedForWrite.hEvent, INFINITE);
if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == returnValue)
{
    cout << "The state of the specified object is signaled." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Wait for single object failed. Error code: " << returnValue << endl;
}

CHAR readBuf[5];
DWORD readSize = 0;
OVERLAPPED overlappedForRead = {};
overlappedForRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

result = ReadFile(serialDeviceHdl, readBuf, 5, &readSize, &overlappedForRead);
if (FALSE == result)
{
    errCode = GetLastError();
    if (ERROR_IO_PENDING == errCode)
    {
        cout << "Overlapped I/O operation is in progress." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Write to device failed. Error code: " << errCode << endl;
    }
}

returnValue = WaitForSingleObject(overlappedForRead.hEvent, INFINITE);
if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == returnValue)
{
    cout << "The state of the specified object is signaled." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Wait for single object failed. Error code: " << returnValue << endl;
}
```

Comment: you not need to call `ResetEvent` - io subsystem auto reset event before begin io. instead `WaitForSingleObject(overlappedForWrite.hEvent..` need usual call `GetOverlappedResult` for not only wait for io finished but get final result too. also this code use by fact synchronous io logic.

Comment: @RbMm Yes, you're right for ResetEvent. Good to know for GetOverlappedResult.